# How to add custom properties for Checkbox in Xamarin Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

In my Xamarin Android application, I am in need of having some custom properties for Checkbox control. We have default properties like 'Id', 'Text', etc.,

Is it possible to add custom properties programmatically to checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

Well doing this in Xamarin.Android is a Piece of Cake:

- First Create your Custom Checkbox by inheriting your class from checkbox control something like this :

  ```
  public class CustomCheckBox: CheckBox
  {

  Context mContext;

  public CustomCheckBox(Context context) : base(context)
  {
      Init(context, null);
  }
  public CustomCheckBox(Context context, Android.Util.IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
  {
      Init(context, attrs);
  }
  public CustomCheckBox(Context context, Android.Util.IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
  {
      Init(context, attrs);
  }
  public CustomCheckBox(Context context, Android.Util.IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
  {
      Init(context, attrs);
  }
  private void Init(Context ctx, Android.Util.IAttributeSet attrs)
  {
      mContext = ctx;
  }
  }
  ```
- Then you can Add your custom properties to it in two different ways
- First, you can create an interface and inherit that interface (Suggested one as it helps you in case you need the same property in some other custom control) i.e Something like this :

  ```
  public class CustomCheckBox : CheckBox , IPropertyCollection
  { ...... }
  ```

  Where IPropertyCollection is something like this :

  ```
  public interface IPropertyCollection 
  {
  long FieldId { get; set; }

  string FieldName { get; set; }

  long PrimaryId { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Second, you can directly add the properties to your control class and the same will be available inside it something like this

  ```
   public class CustomCheckBox : CheckBox 
  { ...... 
    public string FieldName {get; set;}
   }
  ```

Hope It helps,

Goodluck!

Revert in case of any queries

Answer (score 0):

On Android, you can custom properties and custom them in the `.axml` file.

1) add `attrs.xml` file in your values folder.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <resources>
   <declare-styleable name="custom">
     <attr name="test" format="string" />
     <attr name="number" format="integer" />
   </declare-styleable>
 </resources>
```

2) here is your `MyCheckBox` class:

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.Res;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Widget;

namespace App39
{
   public class MyCheckBox : CheckBox
    {

       public string mText { get; set; }
        public int mNumber { get; set; }
        public MyCheckBox(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
        {
            TypedArray ta = context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attrs, Resource.Styleable.custom);

            string text = ta.GetString(Resource.Styleable.custom_test);
            int number = ta.GetInteger(Resource.Styleable.custom_number, -1);
            this.mText = text;
            this.mNumber = number;
            Log.Error("IAttributeSet", "text = " + text + " , number = " + number);

            ta.Recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

2) custom it in your `.axml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <App39.MyCheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    custom:test="111111111"
    custom:number="200">

  </App39.MyCheckBox>
</RelativeLayout>
```

4) in your `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    MyCheckBox myCheckBox;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        myCheckBox = FindViewById<MyCheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkbox);
        //myCheckBox.mNumber;
        //myCheckBox.mText;
    }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/CustomCheckBox), I provide a demo for you.